# Adding adjacent elements of a list

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need to do the following loop in python (in pseudo-code, I'm learning python)

```
listOfNumbers = [1,2,3]
averagesOfNumbers = [0,0,0]

for i = 1 to 2
   averagesOfNumbers [i] = (listOfNumbers [i] + listOfNumbers[i + 1]) / 2
end i
```

averageOfNumbers will look like [1.5, 2.5, 0].

How do I do this in Python?

Comment: What do you mean by `end i`?

Comment: From 1 to 2 meaning just 1?

Comment: [Python For Loops](https://realpython.com/python-for-loop/) and [How to Do Math in Python...](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-do-math-in-python-3-with-operators)

Comment: `average = [(nums[i]+nums[i+1])/2 for i in range(len(nums)-1)]` I'll leave you to disect it and I would suggest looking up Python array manipulation.

Answer (score 1):

See the code if this is what you're looking for:

```
List=[1,2,3]
avg=[0]*len(List)
for i in range(len(List)-1):
    avg[i]=(List[i]+List[i+1])/2
print(avg)
```

Hope you got the code.
Output:
[1.5,2.5,0]

Comment: `list` shadows the built in class

Answer (score 1):

This is how you would do it in Python:

```
listOfNumbers = [1,2,3]
averagesOfNumbers = [0,0,0]

# In Python, range function generates a range of numbers
# starting from 0 if number range is not provided.
# So, range(2) means 0 and 1 in total, that 
# is 2 numbers.

for i in range(2):
    averagesOfNumbers[i] = (listOfNumbers [i] + listOfNumbers[i + 1])/2

print(averagesOfNumbers)
```

Comment: *"2 means 0,1,2"* actually `range(2)` means from 0 up to **but not including** 2. (just 0 and 1)

Comment: @Ayxan Thank you for your correction, I was nothing thinking properly. I fixed it in my answer :)

Answer (score 1):

Wow this is so cool. I never used stackoverflow before. I've always wondered how to get the smart people to help me !!

Here is what gives me the right answer to my homework.

calculate average change, greatest increase, greatest decrease.

```
i = 0
while (i < rowCount - 1):
   diffPL.append(PL[i+1] - PL[i])
    i = i + 1
averageChange = sum(diffPL)/len(diffPL)
greatestIncrease = max(diffPL)
greatestDecrease = min(diffPL)
```

---

Thanks to everyone who offered suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want to do the following:

```
listOfNumbers = [1,2,3]
averagesOfNumbers = [0,0,0]

for i in range(len(listOfNumbers)-1):
    averagesOfNumbers[i] = (listOfNumbers[i] + listOfNumbers[i+1]) / 2
```

Answer (score 0):

```
list_of_numbers = [1, 2, 3] 
averages_of_numbers = [0, 0, 0]

for i in range(0, 2): # this will take indexes 0 and 1    
    averages_of_numbers[i] = (list_of_numbers[i] + list_of_numbers[i+1]) / 2

print(averages_of_numbers)
```

Answer (score 0):

What is the most pythonic way here is to make use of [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/functions.html#zip). This avoids having indexes that you don't really use:

```py
>>> numbers = [1,2,3]
>>> [sum(pair)/2 for pair in zip(numbers, numbers[1:])]
[1.5, 2.5]
```

If you really need to have a zero at the end, you can just add it manually:

```py
numbers = [1,2,3]
avg = [sum(pair)/2 for pair in zip(numbers, numbers[1:])]
avg.append(0)
```

In some cases (eg. you don't need a list, but an iterator) it might even be clearer to use `map`:

```py
>>> map(lambda pair: sum(pair)/2, zip(numbers, numbers[1:]))
<map object ...>
```